# React Native Login

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, api, react-native

I Create login form for React Native App with mysql database 
it seems that it doesn't see the query in my api keep showing the invalid message 'Invalid Username or Password Please Try Again' while the data is correct 
I didn't figure out where is the problem 
please anyone help me on this

**login.js**

```
// Creating Login Activity.
export default class LoginActivity extends Component {

  // Setting up Login Activity title.
  static navigationOptions =
   {
      title: 'LoginActivity',
   };

constructor(props) {

    super(props)

    this.state = {

      UserEmail: '',
      UserPassword: ''

    }

  }

UserLoginFunction = () =>{

 const { UserEmail }  = this.state ;
 const { UserPassword }  = this.state ;


fetch('http://URL', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({

    email: UserEmail,

    password: UserPassword

  })

}).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        // If server response message same as Data Matched
       if(responseJson === 'Data Matched')
        {

            //Then open Profile activity and send user email to profile activity.
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Second', { Email: UserEmail });

        }
        else{

          Alert.alert(responseJson);
        }

      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });


  }
```

this the api I tried different ones but didn't know where is the error exactly

**API**

```
<?php

// Importing DBConfig.php file.
include 'DBConfig.php';

// Creating connection.
 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

 // Getting the received JSON into $json variable.
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

 // decoding the received JSON and store into $obj variable.
 $obj = json_decode($json,true);

// Populate User email from JSON $obj array and store into $email.
$email = $obj['email'];

// Populate Password from JSON $obj array and store into $password.
$password = $obj['password'];

//Applying User Login query with email and password match.
$Sql_Query = "select * from customers where email = '$email' and password = '$password' ";

// Executing SQL Query.
$check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query));


if(isset($check)){

 $SuccessLoginMsg = 'Data Matched';

 // Converting the message into JSON format.
$SuccessLoginJson = json_encode($SuccessLoginMsg);

// Echo the message.
 echo $SuccessLoginJson ; 

 }

 else{

 // If the record inserted successfully then show the message.
$InvalidMSG = 'Invalid Username or Password Please Try Again' ;

// Converting the message into JSON format.
$InvalidMSGJSon = json_encode($InvalidMSG);

// Echo the message.
 echo $InvalidMSGJSon ;

 }

 mysqli_close($con);?>
```